# Execute SQL command with powershell and specifying the domain account

Tags: sql-server, powershell, connection-string

I am putting together some powershell scripts to execute SQL commands against SQL Server and need to specify the windows account to use in the connectionstring. I have tried the following which does not work.

```
$SQLServer = ".\sqlexpress"
$SQLDBName = "dbname"
$uid ="domain\user
$pwd = "password"
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; Integrated Security = false; User ID = $uid; Password = $pwd;"
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.Open();

.... Execute query...
```

I get the following error.

> Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "Login failed for user 
>   'Domain\user'.

I was lead to understand that if you specify false on integrated security then is would take the username and password and connect using the corresponding windows account.

For me this is failing to connect. Am I missing something here ?

Many thanks

Darren

Comment: Ok, I have done some more reading and understand now that the domain account cannot be specified. I need to look at either creating a SQL account or somehow impersonating the domain user.

Comment: You probably should just create the SQL account, and make the SQL account name similar to your program name.

Comment: How we get around this is we use "Integrated Security=true" and execute the PowerShell script using a service account.  I suppose you could also invoke a PSSession passing in a PSCredential object.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to tackle this would be to use the SQL PowerShell Module (SQLPS) which can be obtained by installing "Management Tools" from the SQL Management Studio Installer. By default, when using `Invoke-Sqlcmd` it will connect as the windows account that initiated the PowerShell instance. If you wish to run as another windows account other than the one you are signed in with, you would shift + right click PowerShell and choose option to "run as different user".

Once Module has been installed, you can import module by executing:

```
Import-Module SQLPS
```

Next you would execute your query like the following:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "ServerName\Instance" -Database "DatabaseName" -Query "Some Query Here"
```

While entirely optional, I would recommend adding `-Verbose` as this will show you output just as you would see in Sql Management Studio.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your time answering. I will have a look at this. However, I need run this on a remote box, so won't be able to do the runas thing.

I changed the way I approached the problem by creating a sql login that I now use in a sqlcommand connection string. Which solved the problem, although would have preferred to have impersonated a domain account.

Thanks